# How to implement an interface returns IAsyncResult with empty method body

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

WCF needs me to implement methods like `IAsyncResult OnBeginOpen(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state)` if I want to inherit `ChannelBase`. As I have nothing to do when the channel is getting opened, I'd rather leave that method body empty. What should I return as `IAsyncResult` in those empty methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by Adding an IAsyncResult implementation as a completed async result

```
internal class CompletedAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
    public CompletedAsyncResult(object state)
    {
        this.AsyncState = state;
    }

    public object AsyncState { get; set; }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle => new ManualResetEvent(true);

    public bool CompletedSynchronously => true;

    public bool IsCompleted => true;
}
```

and used like

```
protected override IAsyncResult OnBeginOpen(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    var result = new CompletedAsyncResult(state);
    callback?.Invoke(result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, you should not have empty methods at all. If the `ChannelBase` have an abstract method you don't need, you should either provide a sensible override even if you don't need one right now, or throw a [`NotSupportedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) from it, where the exception message explains why this method is not supported:

```
public override IAsyncResult OnBeginOpen(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state) 
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("OnBeginOpen is not supported because...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My question is really about how to provide the sensible override which does nothing, not literally with "empty body".

Comment: You can simply return `null`, but this opens up the possibility for null reference exceptions down the line - and in that case, it's better to throw a `NotSupportedException` at the source method. The point is that there can't be a sensible override without actually implementing something - and since you don't want to or can't implement this method, the sensible thing to do is throw an exception instead.

Comment: But there is a chance not doing anything is the right move. Like my `Open` method is an empty method because there is nothing it should do. All the initialization job is done in `ChannelFactory`. Now WCF asks me to provide an `OnBeginOpen` method to support opening the channel asynchronously.  The only thing I need `OnBeginOpen` to do is doing nothing, and that should be a valid option. 
I can't just throw something like `NotSupportedException` because it is actually supported, and returning `null` brings the risk of `NullReferenceException`. I just need something like `Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: If your `Open` method is a no-op and your `OnBeginOpen` method is a no-op, perhaps you shouldn't inherit that base class at all. I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish so I can't really offer any more help without more details. This seems to me like an XYProblem right now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm writing up a custom transport channel for WCF. When you inherit the `ChannelBase`, you will have to implement all the abstract methods it provides, and some of them should just do nothing. If the method is a syncronized method, I can just leave the body empty. If it is TPL-based, I return `Task.CompletedTask`. When it is APM, I don't know what's the best solution.

Comment: Sorry, not my area if expertise. Perhaps someone else might come up with a better answer.